# How to use Javascript to play GIF once the it has reached the middle of screen not anywhere in the screen

Tags: javascript, gif

I am trying to find a script that will play my gifs on page when they reach the middle of the screen whilst scrolling. Currently I have this script in place which plays the gif as soon as it comes into screen view. But this is not giving the user enough time to get to the playing animation.
I really appreciate any help on this.
Amy

```
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (rect.middle >= 0) && (rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight);
 }


function animateGifsInScreen() {
    $('.gif').each(function(index, el) {
      if(isScrolledIntoView(el)) {
        $(el).trigger('mouseenter');
      } else {
        $(el).trigger('mouseleave');
      }
    });
}

$(document).scroll(animateGifsInScreen);
```

Comment: Stupid question, but: Do you _have_ to use a gif? A gif is just an image file without really any controls on it AFAIK, and it's very very heavy for its purpose. Modern video format are light and offer more controls.

Comment: Otherwise, I guess just replace the gif with a static picture (from the first frame of the gif?) and then swap the source when it comes into view.

Answer (score 2):

Check this example using github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js ,

**Note: Run this in fullscreen**

```js
var sup = [];
 var playing = null;
 $(function(){
  var i = 0;
  $('.gif').each(function(){
  sup[i] = new SuperGif({ gif:this,   progressbar_height: 0,
   auto_play: false, } );
  sup[i].load();
  i++;
  });
  
var findMiddleElement = (function(docElm){
    var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight,
        elements = $('.image-div'); 

    return function(e){
        var middleElement;
        if( e && e.type == 'resize' )
            viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;

        elements.each(function(){
            var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            // if an element is more or less in the middle of the viewport
            if( pos > viewportHeight/2.5 && pos < viewportHeight/1.5 ){
                middleElement = this;
                return false; // stop iteration 
            }
        });

       if(typeof(middleElement)!='undefined'){
         var index = $(middleElement).index();
         //console.log(index);
         if(playing!=index){
          
          if(typeof(sup[index])!="undefined"){
           if(typeof(sup[playing])!='undefined'){
                sup[playing].pause();  
           }
     
           playing = index;
           sup[playing].play();
          }
         }
       }
    }
})(document.documentElement);

$(window).on('scroll resize', findMiddleElement);
 });
```

```css
   .image-div{
    margin: 25px;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://solarisedesign.co.uk/_themes/solarise/js/libgif.js"></script>
<ul>  
<li class="image-div">  
  <img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/Byana3FscAMGQ/giphy.gif' class='gif' />
</li>
<li class="image-div">
  <img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/Byana3FscAMGQ/giphy.gif' class='gif' />
</li>
<li class="image-div">
  <img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/Byana3FscAMGQ/giphy.gif' class='gif' />
 </li> 
 <li class="image-div">
  <img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/Byana3FscAMGQ/giphy.gif' class='gif' />
 </li> 
 <li class="image-div">
  <img src='https://media.giphy.com/media/Byana3FscAMGQ/giphy.gif' class='gif' />
 </li> 
</ul>
```